# Transformation manipulator rotate keeps messing with my material view

Tags: materials, transforms, windows

Bizarre glitch(?) that seems to happen whenever I use the material view after activating the rotate transformation manipulator on a rig. When I rotate my bones manually, everything seems just fine, but the moment I use the rotate manipulator, parts of my faces just disappear entirely from the material view as if it was being clipped away via distance. The mesh will sometimes appear if I zoom in from far away but then it'll disappear entirely the moment I zoom out slightly. [image]

As I prefer to work in material view most of the time, this is quite annoying, and I'm not sure what to do. Every time I activate the tool the material view will always keep acting this way until I restart blender entirely. I tried checking the clipping view and restarting my computer but to no avail, and searching brings up nothing. Anything I can do? (I'm using version 2.78)

Comment: Tried increasing the clipping distance?

Comment: Tried it multiple times to an absurd degree; this problem persists no matter how close I am to the object too. Weird.

Comment: Could you upload a stripped .blend file so we can isolate it this is an issue on only your side?